# Xamarin.Forms TabbedPage active tab 1 behind selection on iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, prism

I have created a `TabbedPage`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
            prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
            x:Class="MyApp.Views.MainPage"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views;assembly=MyApp"
            xmlns:resources="clr-namespace:MyApp.Common"
            Title="{resources:Translate MainPage_Title}">
    <TabbedPage.Children>
        <local:MapsPage Icon="tabicon_mapspage.png" />
        <local:ProfilePage Icon="tabicon_profilepage.png" />
        <local:StatusPage Icon="tabicon_statuspage.png" />
    </TabbedPage.Children>
</TabbedPage>
```

On Android the tabs works as you would expect. However, on the iOS simulator, the currently active tab is always 1 behind! If i click "status" nothing happens, but when i click anything else after that (either "maps" or "profile") THEN "status" is shown.

I have no custom renderers, do i need one for iOS to make TabbedPage behave as expected?

I have put a very minimal project up here which shows the issue: https://github.com/RandomStuffAndCode/PrismApp

Comment: I test your project but can't reproduce your issue, maybe i misunderstand , could you add a gif image to describe your problem?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to run the code. Apparently its a bug caused by the remote simulator for visual studio. If i run the project on mac i cannot reproduce it either. I have informed Xamarin of the issue and they have confirmed it. Gif here: https://media.giphy.com/media/l378AiPgcUFKLarmw/giphy.gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only present in the remote simulator for visual studio on windows. Using the "native" simulator on mac does not exhibit this behavior. Closing this question as the bug is in tooling, not the Xamarin.Forms framework